# Have navbar search route to single view - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a search bar in my navigation bar, located in application layout. I'd like it to route to my Offer model's index from anywhere in my site and search those records. Though when I submit, it searches within the view that I'm already in. Does the code below have an error which might be causing this?

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
    <%= form_tag(offers_path, :method => :get) do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, nil,
                           {:id => "search-query-2", :placeholder => "Search offers..."} %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :use_keywords, "true" %>
    <% end %>
  </form>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using <form> within <form>? You can add the classes to your form_tag...

Comment: Yes, that's looks like the issue. The outer form gets submitted insted of the inner.

Comment: I don't think you should use a form within another form. You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms

Comment: Thats, that was problem.